# Qt cross compile

Tags: qt, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a Qt4 application on Linux for Windows. I need to create an .exe  (32 bit) from a Qt project, and I'm compiling under Linux (32 bit). Note that I'm not using Qt Creator, I am compiling with `qmake`.

I tried following many other tutorials/answers but I can't seem to make it work. [Some](http://blog.2of1.org/2010/08/23/cross-compiling-a-qt-win32-app-on-linux/) suggest that I need MinGW but I can't find it for my platform (PCLinuxOS). Does anyone know where I can get it? Is there any other solution (apart from using Wine/Windows)?

I already have a copy of the headers and DLLs from Qt4 for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MXE](http://mxe.cc) does exactly what you want. It cross compiles to Windows. It comes with Qt, as well as many other libraries.

It's much easier to use than setting up a MinGW compiler on your own. You can start building in a matter of minutes, rather than spend the whole day setting up a cross compiler manually.

Comment: Quick and easy. Perfect. I'll try it.

Comment: After 8 hours spent compiling Qt, I was able to cross-compile my project. But it compiled with statically linked libraries. Is it possible to use dynamic linking?

Comment: @LordSpectre MXE currently only uses static linking. It's to avoid DLL hell (shared linking would require about 10 DLLs to be shipped with the executable.) But, 8 hours? Did you use all your CPU cores? Like `make qt JOBS=4` on a quad core (`JOBS=8` on an quad i7 with HT)? It takes about 30 minutes on my i5 :-/

Comment: @LordSpectre Oh, btw, I think there's some work going in MXE to make it possible to build shared libraries instead (along with other stuff, like building 64-bit executables.) It's a good idea to ask on the MXE mailing list. The link is on their website.

Comment: I didn't know that I could use JOBS=4... Thanks!